# java.net.ProtocolException: Expected ':status' header not present

Tags: android-asynctask, okhttp, android, gson

I just saw a *Protocol Exception* suddenly in a working app. Starting today all the network calls are failing and getting empty in our application, but the API is working with web browsers.

I updated okHttp & Gson dependencies in my application Gradle but still get the same error. My Server name is nginx .

I also checked same URL in volley and successfully got a response from the server, but I used the same URL and wrote code in Retrofit and it is not working there (no response from server)

Is this related to an android okHttp problem or is it a server-related problem?

MainActivity.java:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    recyclerview = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    tabs_adapter = new Tabs_Adapter(MainActivity.this, topTabList);
    recyclerview.setAdapter(tabs_adapter);

    new AsyncTask<JSONObject, Object, Tabs_Response>() {
        @Override
        protected Tabs_Response doInBackground(JSONObject... jsonObjects) {
            try {
                String url = "https://api.bargaincry.com/apurl/deal/get_ApiCategory/41187";

                Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();

                Response response = new OkHttpClient().newCall(request).execute();

                strResponse = response.body().string();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Tabs_Response tabs_response = new Gson().fromJson(strResponse,Tabs_Response.class);
            return tabs_response;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Tabs_Response tabs_response) {

            if (tabs_response != null && tabs_response.getTopTabs() != null && tabs_response.getTopTabs().size() > 0) {
                topTabList = tabs_response.getTopTabs();
                tabs_adapter = new Tabs_Adapter(MainActivity.this, topTabList);
                recyclerview.setAdapter(tabs_adapter);
            }
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Tap_Response.java:

```
public class Tabs_Response {

@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("top_tabs")
@Expose
private List<TopTab> topTabs = null;

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public List<TopTab> getTopTabs() {
    return topTabs;
}

public void setTopTabs(List<TopTab> topTabs) {
    this.topTabs = topTabs;
}
```

}

TopTab.java:

```
public class TopTab {

@SerializedName("category_id")
@Expose
private String categoryId;
@SerializedName("category_name")
@Expose
private String categoryName;

public String getCategoryId() {
    return categoryId;
}

public void setCategoryId(String categoryId) {
    this.categoryId = categoryId;
}

public String getCategoryName() {
    return categoryName;
}

public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
    this.categoryName = categoryName;
}
```

Tabs_Adapter.java:

```
public class Tabs_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
private Context context;
private List<TopTab> tabList;
private TopTab topTab;

public Tabs_Adapter(Context context, List<TopTab> tabList){
    this.context = context;
    this.tabList = tabList;
}
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView textView;
    public TopTab topTab;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tabtext_data);
    }
}
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_items,parent,false);
    MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return myViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    topTab = tabList.get(position);
    ((MyViewHolder)holder).textView.setText(topTab.getCategoryName());
    ((MyViewHolder)holder).topTab =topTab;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (tabList != null){
        return tabList.size();
}else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

LogCat:

> java.net.ProtocolException: Expected ':status' header not present
>   02-14 11:38:52.468 12631-19978/com.example.srikanth.toptabs_activity
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.FramedTransport.readNameValueBlock(FramedTransport.java:197)
>   02-14 11:38:52.468 12631-19978/com.example.srikanth.toptabs_activity
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.FramedTransport.readResponseHeaders(FramedTransport.java:104)
>   02-14 11:38:52.468 12631-19978/com.example.srikanth.toptabs_activity
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:906)
>   02-14 11:38:52.468 12631-19978/com.example.srikanth.toptabs_activity
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.access$300(HttpEngine.java:92)
>   02-14 11:38:52.468 12631-19978/com.example.srikanth.toptabs_activity
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine$NetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(HttpEngine.java:891)

Answer (score 2):

Update Retrofit and Okhttp3 libraries to this version.

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'

compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed in current versions of OkHttp. Please upgrade.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i upgraded to 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.0' from 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0 but till now get same error

Comment: I also upgraded okhttp3 to   implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1' but didnot get response from server